# DBSCAN Silhouette Coefficients: does this for-loop work?

Tags: python, for-loop, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I'm trying to compare the results of my classmates Silhouette Score calculations to mine, and am having some trouble wrapping my head around their for-loop. I'm not looking for freebies, we've already submitted the below for grading, just trying to understand what's going on here for future reference.

The question:

> Using DBSCAN iterate (for-loop) through different values of min_samples (1 to 10) and epsilon (.05 to .5, in steps of .01) to find clusters in the road-data used in the Lesson and calculate the Silohouette Coeff for min_samples and epsilon.

road-data:

```
             osm         lat          lon         alt
0      144552912    9.349849    56.740876   17.052772
1      144552912    9.350188    56.740679   17.614840
2      144552912    9.350549    56.740544   18.083536
...
434873  93323209    9.943451    57.496270   24.635285

434874 rows × 4 columns
```

(Updated Edit) Normalized:

```
#Normalize sample from dataset
XX = X.copy()
XX['alt'] = (X.alt - X.alt.mean())/X.alt.std()
XX['lat'] = (X.lat - X.lat.mean())/X.lat.std()
XX['lon'] = (X.lon - X.lon.mean())/X.lon.std()
```

Classmates loop:

```
start   = 0.0
stop    = 0.45
step    = 0.01
my_list = np.arange(start, stop+step, step)

startb   = 1
stopb    = 10
stepb    = .2 # To scale proportionately with epsilon increments
my_listb = np.arange(startb, stopb+stepb, stepb)

my_range = range(45)

one = []

for i in tqdm(my_range):
   dbscan = DBSCAN(eps = .05 + my_list[i] , min_samples = 1 + my_listb[i])
   XX.cluster = dbscan.fit_predict(XX[['lat','lon']])
   one.append(metrics.silhouette_score(XX[['lat', 'lon']], XX.cluster))
```

[image: Classmates figure]

My Loop(s):

(I broke my solution up into 10 loops, one for each min_sample (1-10). Examples below.)

```
#eps loop 0.05 to 0.5 (steps 0.01) min_samples=1

eps_range = [x / 100.0 for x in range(5,51,1)]
eps_scores_1 = []
for e in tqdm(eps_range):
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=e, min_samples=1)
labels = dbscan.fit_predict(XX[['lon', 'lat', 'alt']])
eps_scores_1.append(metrics.silhouette_score(XX[['lon', 'lat', 'alt']],labels))
```

-

```
#eps loop 0.05 to 0.5 (steps 0.01) min_samples=2

eps_range = [x / 100.0 for x in range(5,51,1)]
eps_scores_2 = []
for e in tqdm(eps_range):
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=e, min_samples=2)
labels = dbscan.fit_predict(XX[['lon', 'lat', 'alt']])
eps_scores_2.append(metrics.silhouette_score(XX[['lon', 'lat', 'alt']],labels))
```

[image: My Figure]

What I observe, as far as differences:

1. Classmate did not include 'alt' in their for-loop.
2. Classmate attempted some kind of nested loop?
3. Classmate's range is 45, not sure that's right.
4. Classmate's `my_list` is not in the correct notation?
5. Classmate's max Silhouette Scores are much higher than mine.
6. **(not shown)** **Classmate used 10,000 random samples, I used 30,000 random samples.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks for both minors and epsilon to be varied - it called for a *nested* loop. Your classmate used a single loop, and did not consider combinations. You did the outer loop by copy and paste.

Your classmate uses a very misleading way of managing the range, because he adds 0.05 respectively 1 later!

You cannot just mix latitude, longitude, and altitude. They have different units. In fact, you shouldn't even mix latitude and longitude because of distortion - use Haversine distance instead!

Silhouette assumes convex clusters, but DBSCAN does not generate convex clusters.

The sklearn implementation likely treats noise just like a cluster, which will usually give worse results. But Silhouette is not really meant to be used with noise labels...

Comment: I apologize, I should have shared, we did normalize our data.                 
    #Normalize sample from dataset
XX = X.copy()
XX['alt'] = (X.alt - X.alt.mean())/X.alt.std()
XX['lat'] = (X.lat - X.lat.mean())/X.lat.std()
XX['lon'] = (X.lon - X.lon.mean())/X.lon.std()

Comment: I couldn't wrap my head around constructing the nested loop. The long-hand way I went about is correct, yes?

Comment: Normalizing latitude, longitude and altitude is an even worse idea. The data had a physical meaning that you now destroyed...

Comment: And the Silhouette function of sklearn supposedly does not give correct results when you have noise points. Which you will have.

Comment: Thank you for the response, even worse idea relative to? I'm not following you. You make a point none the less. Normalizing does reduce external validity! To you second comment, could you provide me with some more details surrounding your assertion? As I'm sure you can see within the work-space that I outlined in my question, I'm a student that's interested in understanding 'why' over 'it's-just-wrong'.

Comment: Apologies, ignore my most-recent comment. I failed to recognize you were the one that originally posted. Thank you for your observations!

Comment: It -suppposedly- ignores that noise is not a cluster.